# XAMPP Apache Virtual host on NAS

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I tried to create a virtual host for local xampp apache (windows7) with no luck.
What I tried:
hosts contains:

```
127.0.0.5 mycloud
```

httpd-vhosts.conf contains:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.5:80>
    DocumentRoot \\WDMYCLOUD\user
    ServerName mycloud
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    <Directory "\\WDMYCLOUD\user">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache runs as service as local user, not System.
'user' in directory has same password on local machine and NAS. It includes an index.html.

I tried a lot of different variations, but mostly apache won't start. With this configuration apache starts but eror log shows following:

```
[Fri May 15 08:51:49.224900 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 12280:tid 1720] [client 127.0.0.1:53075] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/WDMYCLOUD
```

The network drive must have the letter Z: and not C:.

Can anyone help? Thanks.